# Testing Form symfony with construct

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing

The problem was too old version of PHPunit
/////

Now I have other problem.I have that test:

```
class TodoTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    private $em;
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->em = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        return array(
            new PreloadedExtension([
                new TodoType($this->em)
            ], [])
        );
    }

    public function testTodoType()
    {
        $task = new Todo();
        $form = $this->factory->create(TodoType::class, $task, ['locale' => 'en']);
    }
 }
```

I get this problem:

> Error: Call to a member function getPrioritysInUserLocaleToForm() on null

Problem is here in TodoType class:

class TodoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

```
/**
 * TodoType constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', Type\TextType::class)
        ->add('content', Type\TextareaType::class)
        ->add('priority', Type\ChoiceType::class, [ 'choices' => $this->addChoicesInUserLocale($options['locale']) ])
        ->add('dueDate', Type\DateTimeType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            'html5' => false,
        ]);
}

/**
 * Configure defaults options
 *
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
{
    $resolver->setDefaults( [
        'locale' => 'en',
    ] );
}
/**
 * Method adds array with choices to ChoiceType in builder
 *
 * @param string $locale User's locale
 *
 * @return array All priority in user _locale formatted as array e.g. ['1' => 'low', ...]
 */
private function addChoicesInUserLocale(string $locale): array
{
    return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Priority')
            ->getPrioritysInUserLocaleToForm($locale);
}
```

}

I do not know why it is not working :/

Comment: I found a problem. I was using wrong version of phpunit

Comment: So add this as answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you are trying to call a method on null in this part of the code:

```
return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Priority')
        ->getPrioritysInUserLocaleToForm($locale);
```

That message tells you, that `getRepository()` returns null.

This happens because the EntityManager you use is a mock, which will always return null for all methods unless specified otherwise. You can fix this by making it return an EntityRepository instead. You can do this in your test method:

```
public function testTodoType()
{
    $repoMock = $this->createMock(PriorityRepository::class);
    $repoMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getPrioritysInUserLocaleToForm')
        ->with('en')
        ->willReturn([]); // Whatever you want it to return

    $this->em->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->with('AppBundle:Priority')
        ->willReturn($repoMock);

    $task = new Todo();
    $form = $this->factory->create(TodoType::class, $task, ['locale' => 'en']);
}
```

This will make the EntityManager return your Repository-mock which then in turn returns whatever values you want. The `expects()` calls are assertions and since your test does not have any yet, you might want to check that the repository method is called using `$this->atLeastOnce()` instead of  `$this->any()`. In any case for the test to be useful you have to make assertions at some point.